# Beginner here, trying to start learning arduino, which starter kit should I buy?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm really interested in arduino but I don't know much about it. I want to buy a starter kit to play with, but when I searched it on amazon, there are couple unofficial starter kit and a more expensive official one. So, can some one tell me the major difference between the unofficial starter kit and official starter kit? And which one would you recommend me to buy? Thank you!

Sorry, bonus question: why is the start kit([$89](http://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-starter-kit)) in arduino website is much cheaper than the official starter kit in amazon([$120](http://www.amazon.ca/Arduino-Starter-Official-170-page-Projects/dp/B009UKZV0A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1435770992&sr=8-1&keywords=arduino%20starter%20kit))?

Comment: I can answer the bonus question for you right now:  They're not that much different.  Look at the units.  The "more expensive" one is in Canadian dollars, the cheaper in US dollars. Do the conversion, and there's not that much difference.

Answer (score 2):

You could do worse than a cheap [37-in-1 Sensor Kit](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=37-in-1+sensor+kit) from eBay and any Arduino board of your choice.

Also some [Dupont Jumpers](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=dupont+jumper+wire) are essential.  Get a selection of M/M, M/F and F/F.

Comment: I got the 1st one, and It's of decent quality. I only wish it came with an SD breakout for logging metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to recommend the [oomlout ARDX starter kit](http://oomlout.co.uk/collections/arduino/products/arduino-starter-kit-ardx) to students at the university I work at as it is relatively low cost, widely available, and doesn't have too much cheap filler components that you don't use...